# Creating a Table Valued Function with dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server

I received help previously on creating a query for listing total sales by month for a list of jobs. However, I cannot put this into a view as a variable needs declared.
I thought I could use a Table Valued Function (which I've never used before) but apparently I need to define the columns of the table which I cannot do if they are to be dynamic (the columns are yyyy-mm).
Can someone suggest how I could approach this problem please?

I am not familiar with creating anything other than views so this is completely new to me. Obviously if using the TVF isn't the best method please advise.

The query:

```
 Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' +     QuoteName(YearMonth) From v_JobSalesByMonth  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
 Select  @SQL = '
    Select [JobID], [TotalJobSales],' + @SQL + '
        From (
        Select JobID
         ,TotalJobSales = sum(SalesForMonth) over (Partition By JobID)
         ,YearMonth
         ,SalesForMonth
         From v_JobSalesByMonth A) A
         Pivot (sum(SalesForMonth) For [YearMonth] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

I started to create the function but am confused about how to define the dynamic columns.

```
CREATE FUNCTION db.tvfnJobSalesByMonthPivot (@JobID INT)
RETURNS @JobSalesByMonth TABLE
(
JobID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
TotalJobSales decimal(6,2) NULL,
2016-12 (ermmmmm?)
)
```

Many thanks in advance.
Paul

Comment: `Dynamic queries` cannot be used inside `Functions`. Use `Stored Procedure` instead

Comment: What exactly you will pass as input in third parameter? If it is dynamic then how will you pass it. The column list can be found inside the stored procedure itself and use it in dynamic query

Comment: OK, so using a stored procedure is the only suitable method in this case? Sorry, I obviously misunderstood the purpose of the TVF. I will look up how to create a stored procedure for it if that's the case.